# What would you call size that fits between small and medium?

Tags: single-word-requests

Our UI supports small (32px wide), medium (64px) and large buttons (96px).

Now need appeared to add 48px wide buttons and it would be nice not to rename all the rest, just to give them a name which will fit them between 'small' and 'medium'. Can you suggest that?

Informal names are okay.

Comment: you could also have interesting feedback on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "No'-as-big-as-Medium-but-bigger-than-Small" (as Terry Pratchett's Pictsies would say)?

Comment: @TimLymington, Pratchett would have had a character (Medium Dave Lilywhite, maybe?) call it "extra medium".

Comment: from a usability perspective, you are doing it wrong if you need a label for every size. Labels are meaningless in such a respect, as are pixels (could you mentally visualize 96px if you werent one of the developers?) ask how you can improve your approach on ux.stackexchange

Comment: Why wouldn't it be nice to rename the rest? As one of the answers mentions, using a 'extra-large' label might be suitable.

Comment: What's wrong with just calling them `btnSize32px`, `btnSize48px` and so on?

Comment: how about mezzanine?

Comment: @Ben: Changing the API, versus just extending it: breaking backwards compatibility with whatever uses it.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung: the problem with "extra medium" is that it isn't obvious whether it means "less than medium" or "more than medium".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As a neologism, it can be **smedium**

There are [urbandictionary entries](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smedium&page=2) also. Here is one:

> when a size small is too small and the size medium is too big you are a size smedium!!
>
> *They don't have my size I can't fit the small or the medium if only they had a smedium!*

---

Other than that, you can use different degrees of small like **extra small**. So small fits between extra small and medium.

**Note:** I treated the question as context-free as well for future reference. You can also get useful answers about user interface/technical approaches on ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: +1 Smedium is a great word. I'm going to have to use that often enough to remember it. "No, actually, it's not small at all, I think you'll find it's closer to smedium, so there."

Comment: Or *smish*, halfway between *smallish* and *mediumish*.

Comment: You might as well make up a gibberish word as use **smedium**.

Comment: @Oldcat I think he just did

Comment: Also pronounced/spelled *[Schmedium](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Schmedium)* on occasion

Comment: @bib why not just 'smallish'?

Comment: Because that suggests closer to *small* than *medium* and that would be unfair to hard working, much maligned *medium*.

Comment: That would make `sm`, `smd` and `md`. Nice!!

Answer (score 32):

Keeping the same convention, combine the two?

> Small, **Medium-small**, Medium, Large

Comment: There's an ambiguity in this name, as in 'very small, medium-small, larger-than-small'.

Answer (score 12):

I go with "medium-small" (with or without the hyphen).

The size between medium and small is like the direction between North and West (Northwest)

Similarly, the size between Medium and Large is Medium-Large,

This also fits nicely with how we order steaks:
Rare
Medium-Rare
Medium
Medium-Well
Well Done

Comment: Using any other answer would be a mis-steak

Answer (score 8):

Several user interfaces use **[compact](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compact)** as another word for “small.” For example, Gmail and Google Docs offer compact controls as a slightly-tighter-than-medium setting. It’s also an established term for small cars.

Answer (score 7):

**smaller** might be OK as long as you take medium to mean 'normal'.

Not quite the same as CSS font-size 'smaller' but I think the meaning is clear, it's not medium and it's not small.

**smallish** if you prefer.

Learn the lesson not to call 'styles' by a common enumeration, small=size32, medium=size64, large=size96. Then you can add in as many different sizes as you want, you can easily slip in a size48 without worrying about any knock on effect to other styles.

Comment: *Smallish* is good. *Smaller* should be smaller than *small*, though.

Comment: I'm afraid ***smaller*** doesn't cut it, because there's no obvious way to indicate whether you mean *smaller than medium* or *smaller than **small***. In which context I would just note that the "subtitle font size" selection control in VLC media player uses *smaller* and *larger* for the two extremes (beyond *small* and *large*).

Comment: I had it in my mind that the 'naming' was internal and only the developers would have to know that smaller came between medium and small, I guess if that was the case this question would be on SO rather than here.

Answer (score 6):

> small (32px wide),  **small-plus** (48px), medium (64px),
>   **medium-plus** (80px) and large (96px).

Adding *plus* immediately after the adjective effectively shows it is the next size up, and it's easily shortened to **small +** and **medium +**

Answer (score 5):

You should probably bite the bullet and rename your existing "small" to "extra small", then call your new size "small". Every other answer, although valid, will confuse your users.

Comment: I like this approach, although my recommendation would be to go in the other direction, so that the four button sizes are ultimately _small, medium, large,_ and _extra large._ (Or, if the O.P. would prefer a single word, _jumbo_ could be used instead of _extra large_.)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would add the exact sizes to all the buttons and leave the 48 pixel button without a second label.

Small (32 px) --  (48 px)  -- Medium (64px) -- Large (96 px)

Comment: This would work, if they add a size between medium and large as well, such that the scaling is consistent.

Comment: I need to use textual name without digits in several places.

Answer (score 4):

I'm seriously considering **SUBMEDIUM** as 'smaller than medium'.

It doesn't clearly state to be middle between the two but gives a clear depiction of the order.

Comment: You could similarly use **UBERSMALL**.

Answer (score 3):

small / medium / large / jumbo

I like the idea of creating an extra size on the large end of the spectrum rather than the small end of the spectrum because of the difference in sizes.

32 / 48 / 64 have a difference of 16 between them and 64 / 96 have a difference of 32.

"Jumbo" is also a fun word and seems to connote inordinately large.

I used to work at a concession stand that had only one size of drink. Only the drink price was listed. People would often ask what size it was. I would say, "We only have one size: double extra jumbo!" poking fun at the crazy names and sizes of portions in movie theaters.

Answer (score 2):

How about "MS" for "medium small?"

[For example, ST stands for small tall, MS for medium small, and ML for medium large. Here's a list of the most common wetsuit sizes available.](http://our-lifez1.blogspot.fr/2011_03_05_archive.html)

Comment: Those abbreviations are definitely region-specific! I've _never- heard of "ST/ML".

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Those are sizes specifically applied to wetsuits.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Still: no, not in my part of the world :-)

Answer (score 2):

"Under-medium" or "medium-minus" would leave room for "over-small" or "small-plus".

Answer (score 2):

I have done a lot of websites with inventory (mainly this applies to shirts) and have always combined.  I am leaving this as my own answer because every other answer is combining the opposite as I have seen/used.  To me it is always the smallest first.

```
Here are the default sizes I set in the back end for shirts for one company.  

- xxx-small
- xx-small
- x-small
- small
- small/medium
- medium
- medium/large
- large
- x-large
- xx-large
- xxx-large
- xxxx-large
- xxxxx-large
```

Note that this is the available options I have for the store to choose from.  I don't think they have ever chosen all for one shirt.  For instance most women clothing goes from x-small to xx-large.  Also they might not use any of the "in-between" sizes.  You really shouldn't do this unless you are very very specific on what size your small and medium would be.  The only differences between sites is that some use the dash - so "small-medium", some abbreviate - so "s/m", and some use numbers for the x's - so "4x-large".  Never used a bigger size first nor a smedium.  Might be a cool size for a drink but I am not sure a serious site would use it for clothing or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

"grande"

If Starbucks can create an arbitrary and dissonant list of names for a partial ordering of volumes, so can you.

Answer (score 2):

**smallish**, not completely small, just a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

**Small-medium**.

That way you get to have no digits in the name of the size and it's pretty obvious what the size is without context (unlike other confusing propositions).

Analogically to [compass point naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass#Compass_point_names), 48px would be right between 32px and 64px on your scale.

```
32 px      48 px        64 px        72 px       92 px
Small − Small-Medium − Medium − (Medium-Large) − Large
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would **Thumbnail** work?

[Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post%5fThumbnails) uses Thumbnail as the description for its small image sizes.

[Wikipedia description for Thumbnail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbnail):

> Thumbnails are reduced-size versions of pictures, used to help in recognizing and organizing them, serving the same role for images as a normal text index does for words.

Answer (score 1):

For my user interface elements, I've adopted Bootstrap's sizing system: xs, sm, md, lg. It works nicely in all my scenareos.

Answer (score 1):

1. Re-name what you currently call "small" to "tiny."  Now …
2. … you can have "tiny", "small", and "medium" as you wished.

Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a nod from TeX and use capitalisation provided that it fits your use case.

```
small -> Small -> SMALL -> medium -> Medium -> MEDIUM -> large -> Large -> LARGE
```

...would be your new spectrum of possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

Using Sydney coffee sizes as a guide, how about Regular or Normal?